# PHP PDO transaction issues

Tags: php, transactions, pdo

I have a simple try catch which is not operating how I would expect. This is my first try at using transactions with PDO:

```
try
        {
            $dbo = Db::init();
            $dbo->beginTransaction();
            $dbo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE {$this->table}");
            $dbo->exec($insert);
            $dbo->commit();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $dbo->rollBack();
            echo 'Failed to sync ' . $this->table; 
        }
```

The problem is, if the `$dbo->exec($insert);` fails, the `$dbo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE {$this->table}");` does not get rolled back. Any ideas?

Comment: A string (which is working). But if I purposefully put a syntax error in it to have it throw an exception, when it rolls back, it does not rollback to before the wipe of the table happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` cannot be rolled back. Use `DELETE` instead.

Comment: With this retain the table and it's structure? I only want to delete the data but not the table itself.

Comment: @Headspin: `DELETE FROM table` --- will delete all the rows (it will be slower though, but supports rollbacks)

Comment: @Headspin: `DELETE FROM tablename`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using MySQL, TRUNCATE TABLE has an implicit COMMIT. From the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html :

```
As of MySQL 5.0.8, truncate operations cause an implicit commit. Before 5.0.8, truncate operations are not transaction-safe; an error occurs when attempting one in the course of an active transaction.
```